# wix react-native-navigation change tab animation

Tags: android, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

Is there any way to animate the transition between screens with bottomTabs layout in react-native-navigation?

expected behavior:

[image]

react-native: 0.61.1

react-native-navigation: 3.2.0

```
{
    bottomTabs: {
        id: 'BottomTabs',
        children: [
            {
                stack: {
                    children: [
                        {
                            component: {
                                id: 'tab1',
                                name: 'Tab2Screen',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                            icon: homeIcon,
                            text: 'Tab1'
                        },
                    },
                },
            }, {
                stack: {
                    children: [
                        {
                            component: {
                                id: 'tab2',
                                name: 'Tab2Screen',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                            icon: 'homeIcon',
                            text: 'Tab2'
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Did you found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along those lines:
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/style-animations